# Printing the symbol table from elf file

Tags: segmentation-fault, elf

I am trying to print the symbol table from an elf file. I got the offsets of sections .symtab and .strtab ( I crosschecked with readelf). but the program is giving segmentation fault. Here is the code in question:

```
printf("\n\nSymbol table:");

for(i=0;i<symtab.sh_size/symtab.sh_entsize ;i++)
{
    fseek(ElfFile,symtab.sh_offset+i*symtab.sh_entsize,SEEK_SET);
    fread(&elfSym,1,sizeof elfSym,ElfFile);

    printf("\nSymbol:%s,size:%u",elfSym.st_name+strtab.sh_offset,elfSym.st_size);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the bug:

```
printf("\nSymbol:%s,size:%u",elfSym.st_name+strtab.sh_offset,elfSym.st_size);
```

The `sym.st_name` gives you offset into the `.strtab` section where the symbol name begins, and `strtab.sh_offset` gives you offset *into the file* to where that section begins.

But adding two offsets does not give you a memory location that you can print with `%s`, it gives you *offset* into the file where that string is. You still need to read from file at that offset into memory, and *then* you will be able to print it.